# gliUnimplemented error during standard opengl calls on iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, exc-bad-access

I have xcode 3.2.5 x64. Im creating a standard iphone openglES template application. By default iphone simulator 4.2 is set.

The problem is, that i cant use some of the opengl funcions, like: glMatrixMode, glEnableClientState and some others, beucase I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS msg. Call stack shows, that last method was gliUnimplemented.

By default opengl context is created with SE2 api

```
EAGLContext *aContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
```

, but if I change to SE1 api, those functions works fine and I dont have any errors. Why those functions crashes in SE2 context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2 doesn't have deprecated functionality like matrices, lights or immediate mode.

Comment: yes, but VBO is not deprecated, and it requires glEnableClientState function, which crashes in this SE2 context.

Comment: @majak glEnableClientState is not part of GL ES 2.0, and is not required to use VBOs.